# Google Docs - Prevent automatic sharing with Google accounts outside our domain

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-authentication

Note: **Without restricting it domain wide.**

If I share a document with an individuals email, they are sent a link that contains an access token. They can use this link, and this link only, to access a restricted spreadsheet.

However, if they sign into their personal gmail accounts and then go back to that link, the document auto-shares to their personal gmail account. They, and anyone else that has access to that gmail account, can now access the spreadsheet without having to navigate to the specific link.

How do I prevent this auto-sharing from happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a simplistic answer, but I hope it helps.

The problem can be resolved by controlling Enum Access (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access) and Enum Permission (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

I'd recommend using something like:

```
var file = DriveApp.createFolder('NameOfFile');
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

This way the people getting the email with access to the file can only access it from their domain email addresses, and not their personal ones. Plus, anyone on the domain can find and view it. The two links there should give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert), if a script uses services that can access private data, you'll see authorization dialog. Scripts that you have previously authorized will also ask for additional [authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) if a code change adds new services. All requests to Google Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

**HTTP request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions
```

In the request body, you can set the required properties like `role` and `type` the allowed values are `user, group, domain and anyone`.

```
private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
String value, String type, String role) {
Permission newPermission = new Permission();

newPermission.setValue(value);
newPermission.setType(type);
newPermission.setRole(role);
try {
return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}
return null;
}
```

you may also try to check this  [document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en) which discuss how to set sharing permissions.

Comment: This is not related to the Drive API, or to Google Apps Script, there will be no OAuth flows asking for authorization. I may have added that tag in error. The automatic sharing with any Google account that is logged in when the URL is navigated to is the issue, and as said in the OP this is not something that can just be restricted domain wide. We have many use cases for documents to be shared with external accounts or domains.